# Stripe Google Pay Button is not showing for me on the UI despite

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, angular7, google-pay

I've used the Stripe Payment Request Button HTML code from the stripe docs on https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button to incorporate the Google Pay button on my UI but the stripe component is not showing on my webpage.

The HTML code that I took from Stripe Docs does not show any errors or exceptions on the developer console, the iframe component can be seen on the Elements tab but the button is not being rendered on the UI

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_ozjVjOVezSxwrwsoF4BnqtII');

const paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  total: {
    label: 'Demo total',
    amount: 1000,
  },
});

const elements = stripe.elements();
const prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
  paymentRequest,
});

paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then((result) => {
  if (result) {
    prButton.mount('#payment-request-button');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('payment-request-button').style.display = 'none';
  }
});

paymentRequest.on('token', (ev) => {
  console.log(ev);
  ev.complete('success');
});
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle or working example

Comment: Log out what `result` contains in the Promise resolver of `canMakePayment`. It's probably empty, which means that you probably don't have a card saved in your browser, which is required for the button to show up.

Comment: Already card details are saved in the browser but still, I didn't getting a button to show up. @PaulAsjes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/attystripe/6wythkz8/ I followed this jsfiddle. it will work in a normal HTML but it will not work in angular 7. I console the **result** it will show the same output

Comment: @NaveenKumar, the jsfiddle provided is working for me. Are you saying that it works with plain old HTML but doesn't work with Angular? If so, can you share the Angular jsfiddle example? Also, which browsers are you experiencing this on?